# Regular expressions to filter text

Tags: objective-c, regex, cocoa

in objective-c I have a string as follows:

```
CAST(407704969.734560,
```

I want to extract the digits:

```
407704969.734560
```

The code I'm using is this one:

```
NSString *stringToCheck = @"CAST(407704969.734560,"
NSRange   searchedRange = NSMakeRange(0, [stringToCheck length]);
NSString *pattern = @"(?<=CAST\\()(\\d+?.?\\d+?)(?=,)";
NSError  *error = nil;

NSRegularExpression* regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern options:0 error:&error];
NSArray* matches = [regex matchesInString:stringToCheck options:0 range: searchedRange];
for (NSTextCheckingResult* match in matches) {
    NSString* matchText = [stringToCheck substringWithRange:[match range]];
    NSLog(@"match: %@", matchText);
}
```

I guess the problem is in the regex, seen that I can't find any tutorial about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using following regex:

**PATTERN**

```
CAST\((\d+?\.?\d+?),
```

**INPUT**

```
CAST(407704969.734560,
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Match 1: CAST(407704969.734560,
Group 1: 407704969.734560
```

Or if you only need the digits try this:

**PATTERN**

```
(?<=CAST\()(\d+?\.?\d+?)(?=,)
```

**INPUT**

```
CAST(407704969.734560,
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Match 1: 407704969.734560
```

And here you have not long but really nice regex tutorial:

[www.codeproject.com](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9099/The-30-Minute-Regex-Tutorial)

Comment: Tafari - In both cases, I believe you need to escape the period: `\.`. Otherwise, `407704969!734560` will match.